# Cast a superclass for a generic subclass and add to list

Tags: java, generics

i have a classes like Button, Pane, Checkbox etc.. All of this classes extends from class Element. 
i have a method

```
public synchronized  <T extends Element>  List<T> getAllElements() {
   List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(by);
   List<T> customElements = new ArrayList<>();

   for(int i=0; i<elements.size();i++){
   customElements.add((T) new Element(By.xpath("("+getXpath(by)+")["+i+1+"]")));
}
return customElements;
}
```

but i got class cast exception when try to execute 
    List< Button > btns = anybutton.getAllElements();

How to avoid this or solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: What is `anybutton`?  What is the complete exception message + stack trace?

Comment: Why you think that `new Element` should be instance of `Button`?

Comment: You basically cast `Element` to `Button` - how do you suppose this to work? What do you want to do with this method anyway?

Comment: I have classCastException when try to do something with rlement from list. @tsolakp Button should be instance of element.

Comment: @lexicore because Button extends Element and i should be avle to do this. I need this method for automation

Comment: @AlexKvasko No. If `Button` extends `Element` you can assign `Button` to `Element`, not the other way round.

Comment: @Alex Kvasko. Button is instance of Element but not the other way around. `(Button)new Element(..)` will throw `ClassCastException` but `(Element)new Button(..)` wont.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the generic method that you have you need to make sure that it always returns the type of objects that your calling code is expecting. The usual pattern to achieve this is to pass the type of object the calling code is expecting in form of `Class<T>`.

Here is modified version of your code that can guarantee that and avoid runtime `ClassCastException`.

```
public static  <T extends Element>  List<T> getAllElements(Class<T> clazz) {
    List<WebElement> elements = getDriver().findElements(by);
    List<T> customElements = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0; i<elements.size();i++){
        T element = null;
        try{
            element = clazz.getConstructor( new Class[]{String.class} ).newInstance( By.xpath("("+getXpath(by)+")["+i+1+"]") );     
        }catch(Exception e){
            //log or handle reflection related exceptions
        }
        customElements.add(element);
    }
    return customElements;
 }
```

The above assumes that your `Button` class has a constructor that takes whatever `By.xpath("("+getXpath(by)+")["+i+1+"]")` returns. You can of course modify it to work with your actual types. The most important thing here is that there are no casts in here.

Comment: thank you, can i chage Class<T> with something like "this" to avoid sending class as parameter?

Comment: You cant. `this` represents calling object and not the expectet type.

Comment: but this.class represents a type?

Comment: As I said it does not represent the expected type. You need to call your method like this: `List< Button > btns = anybutton.getAllElements(Button.class);`